# How to retrieve particular table particular value

Tags: magento-1.9, database

how to get single row data. this code is retrieving all data in table.

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');   
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('customimgupload'=>'customimgupload'));

$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);

foreach($alldata as $img)
   {
     echo $img['image_url'];?><br/><?php 
   }

?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add limit it will show the single record `->limit(1, 1)`

```
$pro_id=10;// add your desired product id
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');   
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('customimgupload'=>'customimgupload'))->where('customimgupload.product_id=?', $pro_id);

$alldata =$readconnection->fetchRow($allrecord);

 echo $alldata['image_url'];?><br/><?php
```

Comment: I want to load product id and get that particular image

Comment: what you column name for product id?

Comment: product_id......

Comment: Call to a member function select() on a non-object

Comment: updated the code try it

Comment: I need to display image url based on product id but now no display anythig

Comment: did you pass the image id to variable?

Comment: <?php $pro_id=SF100;// add your desired product id
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');   
$readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read'); 

$allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('customimgupload'=>'customimgupload'))->where('customimgupload.product_id=?', $pro_id)->limit(1, 1);

$alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
foreach($alldata as $img)
{
 echo $img['image_url'];?><br/><?php 
}     

?>

Comment: Still same only not display anythig

Comment: SF100 this is not product it i think check you table column there is id present?

Comment: No i add custom product id so that i want to retrive

Comment: it is there or not?

Comment: ya it's there product_id

Comment: can you post the table image to with data??

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: update the code try that............. check for space if there is space or not

Comment: it display this 7h11S211m

Comment: updated the answer try that n feedback

Comment: is it possible to add one more field here where('customimgupload.product_id=?

Comment: like device_id fileld name

Comment: `echo $alldata['device_id'];` like that you will get all column values

Comment: No no get image based on product_id & device_id

Comment: is it right $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('customimgupload'=>'customimgupload'))->where('customimgupload.product_id & customimgupload.device_id =?', $pro_id,$device_id);

Comment: `$readconnection->select()->from(array('customimgupload'=>'customimgupload'))->wh‌​ere('customimgupload.product_id=?',$pro_id))->wh‌​ere('customimgupload.device_id =? $device_id);` add condition like that

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty

Comment: $readconnection->select()->from(array('customimgupload'=>'customimgupload'))->where('customimgupload.product_id=?',$pro_id)->where('customimgupload.device_id =?' ,$device_id);

Comment: this correct syntax..

Comment: Hi did you face this problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109583/price-not-display-pdf-and-website

Answer (score 1):

Use `fetchRow` instead of `fetchAll`

Comment: `fetchOne` returns a single value not array. Instead of `fetchRow` is correct it return array.

Comment: Right. I was looking in the wrong adapter. Thanks.