# Price Not display pdf and website

Tags: magento-1.9, price, invoice

**Indian Rupee** not display in pdf also My system Front end also I try some other system in frontend working but downloading `Invoice pdf`it shows `&#8377;`

I check all tutorial still same no changes. What is the problem?

```
app/etc/local.xml

<charset>utf8</charset>

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/Rupee_Foradian.ttf');
```

I download Font and upload here `lib/LinLibertineFont/Rupee_Foradian.ttf`

[image]

Here what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

However I post the answer that make it working well..

1. Download the font that support Indian Rupee symbol. I download
   dejavu-sans font.
2. Place the font in lib directory
3. Please override this file 
   `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php` and
   `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php`

and replace

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf');
```

with

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/dejavu-sans/DejaVuSans.ttf');
```

(in `_setFontRegular(), _setFontBold(), _setFontItalic()` functions in both files.)

Comment: I already tried this also but no luck