# Renamed File Not store in Database

Tags: magento-1.9, database

**Renamed** File Not store in Database **Original Name** only stored in Database But **Media** Folder it store Renamed File.

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'FanBook'.DS;
$destFile = $path.'/'.$_FILES['img']['name'];
$filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
$uploader->save($path, $filename);
$img ='FanBook/'.$filename;

 $collection = Mage::getModel('fanbook/fanbook');
$collection ->setData('img',$img);
$collection->save();
```

Comment: sorry don't understand you updating it or same file name problem?

Comment: let us assume i upload file name called : new photo it stored it DB new photo in Media new_photo if i get DB Image it worn't work because it have space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will resolve your space problem

```
$destFile = $path.'/'.str_replace(' ','_',$_FILES['img']['name']);
```

Comment: Did you face this problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109583/price-not-display-pdf-and-website